# how to use localStorage in angular template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, local-storage

I am working with localStorage on a website and I can't get a * ngif to work the way I want.

Explanation:
When a user identifies himself, his information is saved in the localStorage through the variable 'identity'.
I want to show some buttons when the 'identity' variable exists and show others when it doesn't.
But it always shows me the same, whether or not that variable exists in the localStorage.
I suspect that the error is in the template and in how I use the conditional. Although it could also be that I am missing some additional function in another file, but I don't know.

It works fine (in the console I see how It saves the user information), but when I want to use information from it in a conditional directive it doesn't work well.

My code:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public identity:any;

  constructor(
    private _userService:UserService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.identity = this._userService.getIdentity();;
  }

}
```

**getIdentity()**

```
 getIdentity(){
    this.identity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')|| '{}');
        
    
    return this.identity;
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div *ngIf="identity ; else userloggedOut">

        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

      <ng-template #userloggedOut >
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">

      <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Identificarse</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Registrarse</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </ng-template>
```

Comment: Your if condition seems incorrect. If will never be undefined and it’s an or (||). Remove that part.

Comment: Also.. the stringify is not needed if you change to JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('identity')|| null); so that whole if block can go and you can simply return identity.

Comment: you are right (it is already corrected), but that doesn't solve my problem. What could it be?

Comment: I'm sure it has to do with how I do the comparison in the * ngif .. when there is no logged in user and I do console.log(identity) it shows me empty keys {}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
*ngIf="identity || identity != {} ;
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work. Compare with braces does not work because 'identity' is an object. Anyway, I already solved it (incorrectly but it works) by making a boolean function where I check that an attribute of that object has data.